# Should I consolidate improperly used answers for a question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question [What is the new Frenzy status effect in MH4U?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/207571/37419) and a new user user has added multiple answers that all seem to be very much related to one another: [first](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/214026/37419), [second](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/214148/37419), [third](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/214149/37419), [fourth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/214027/37419).  Short of one that is flatly a comment, they all seem to be in the same vein of the user's thought.

Should I combine the answers together, flag them, or just downvote them?  Additionally, if combining the answers is correct, what do I do to the answers that would become redundant?

Answer (score 3):

As near as I can tell by *trying* to read those, *none of them* actually answer the question, so I deleted them all.

In the future, you can just flag them as Not An Answer.

If they *do* somehow combine to comprise a single coherent answer, well... first of all, I don't see it, but, that said, the appropriate thing to do is edit all of the content into a single post and flag the others.

*THAT SAID*, there are situations in which a single user may legitimately post multiple answers to a question. For example, if there is more than one solution to a puzzle, or strategy for a boss, it's perfectly legitimate to post each of them as separate answers. That's clearly not what's going on here, but the caveat remains.

Comment: Well, one of the answers was moderately useful since it described an additional way to get rid of the status effect from the question that wasn't mentioned in the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Assuming it's the only one with a positive score, I converted it to a comment on the existing answer. It's a clarification at best, and does not actually answer the question itself, as near as I can tell.

Comment: Rockin, I see the comment.  I just wanted to make sure that information was preserved because it was useful.